# How to get the \bar over a relation?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

When adding a `\bar` to a relation the spacing around the relation is removed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$x > y$ $x \bar{>} y$

\end{document}
```

So, how does one do this correctly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The name "relation" is the key: you must tell `TeX` that you want a math relation with `\mathrel`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$x > y$, $x \bar{>} y$, $x \mathrel{\bar{>}} y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

By default `>` is already a Rel atom, but `\bar{>}` is turned into an Ord atom, just like `x` and `y`, and you find no spacing between them (try `x{>}y`).

Comment: To be *extremely* fussy, `\bar{>}` yields an Acc[ent] atom, which, however, is eventually “turned into an Ord atom”, as the answer correctly states, once the accent has been dealt with.

Answer (score 11):

Here are three other possibilities: with the `\widebar` symbol from `mathabx`, a simple `\overline`, and with `\stackrel` which, by definition, does not remove the relation spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

$x \mathrel{\widebar{>}} y$

$x \mathrel{\mkern1.8mu\overline{\mkern-1.8mu>\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern1.5mu} y$

$x \stackrel{\raisebox{-0.7ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\relbar$}}{>} y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Do you really want a bar over `>` or do you need simply something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
x \eqslantgtr y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Not a general answer for the problem of getting a bar over a relation symbol, but a specific solution for `<` and `>`. Using `\mathrel` around the construction is necessary anyway.

The idea here is to rotate `\leq` and `\geq` by 180 degrees. However, `\mathrel{\bar{<}}` and `\mathrel{\bar{>}}` might be better, depending on the intended meaning of the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\barlt}{\bar@glt{\geq}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bargt}{\bar@glt{\leq}}

\newcommand{\bar@glt}[1]{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\bar@glt@aux{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\bar@glt@aux}[2]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\barlt b\bargt c$ $a\leq b \geq c$

$a\leq b\geq c$

$a_{\barlt\bargt}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Generally, `< > =` are called as relational operators, LaTeX some spaces are fixed for relational operators, if you give this symbol into braces, then those spaces are removed, so give the tag within `\mathrel` command, e.g, `$x > y$ $x \mathrel{\bar{>}} y$`